# Advanced slicing when passed list instead of tuple in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In the docs, it says (emphasis mine):

> Advanced indexing **is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a
>   non-tuple sequence object**, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool),
>   or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type
>   integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer
>   and Boolean.
>
> <snip>
>
> Also recognize that `x[[1,2,3]]` will trigger advanced indexing, **whereas
>   `x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` will trigger basic slicing**.

I know why `x[(1, 2, slice(None))]` triggers basic slicing. But why does `x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` trigger basic slicing, when `[1,2,slice(None)]` meets the condition of being a non-tuple sequence?

---

On a related note, why does the following occur?

```
>>> a = np.eye(4)
>>> a[(1, 2)]  # basic indexing, as expected
0.0
>>> a[(1, np.array(2))] # basic indexing, as expected
0.0

>>> a[[1, 2]]  # advanced indexing, as expected
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
>>> a[[1, np.array(2)]]  # basic indexing!!??
0.0
```

Comment: No doubt the secret lies [somewhere in the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L166-L721)

Comment: In the current documentation, that last quoted line has been modified to reference legacy code that's in the process of depreciation.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an exception to that rule. The Advanced Indexing documentation section doesn't mention it, but up above, near the start of the [Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) section, you'll see the following text:

> In order to remain backward compatible with a common usage in Numeric, **basic slicing is also initiated if the selection object is any non-ndarray sequence (such as a list) containing slice objects**, the Ellipsis object, or the newaxis object, but not for integer arrays or other embedded sequences.

---

`a[[1, np.array(2)]]` doesn't quite trigger basic indexing. It triggers an undocumented part of the backward compatibility logic, as described in a [comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L200) in the source code:

```
    /*
     * Sequences < NPY_MAXDIMS with any slice objects
     * or newaxis, Ellipsis or other arrays or sequences
     * embedded, are considered equivalent to an indexing
     * tuple. (`a[[[1,2], [3,4]]] == a[[1,2], [3,4]]`)
     */
```

The `np.array(2)` inside the list causes the list to be treated as if it were a tuple, but the result, `a[(1, np.array(2))]`, is still an advanced indexing operation. It ends up applying the `1` and the `2` to separate axes, unlike `a[[1, 2]]`, and the result ends up looking identical to `a[1, 2]`, but if you try it with a 3D `a`, it produces a copy instead of a view.

Comment: This documentation is still incomplete though, because `a[[1, np.array(2)]]` triggers basic indexing

Comment: @Eric: No it doesn't; it triggers advanced indexing. The results happen to look the same if `a` is 2D, but try it with a 3D `a`, and you'll find that the result is a copy instead of a view.

Comment: What i mean is that `a[[1, np.array(2)]]` is different to `a[[1, np.array(2)],]` (for `a` 2d) - the former is the same as `a[(1, 2)]`, the latter is `a[[1, 2]]`. So isn't the former basic indexing? Or is there some middle-undocumented ground?

Comment: No seriously: https://ideone.com/3jXIjz. Just because you don't think it should be different doesn't mean that it is!

Comment: wait, you're right, that is a weird interaction. I was thinking of the `1` and the `np.array(2)` as advanced indexing on separate axes, but they should be along the same axis.

Comment: I don't think passing indices in this format is officially supported, what with the array inside a list, but I'm not sure exactly what's happening. It seems to be treating the outer list as a tuple, as in the basic indexing backward compatibility special case, and then performing advanced indexing anyway.

Comment: The comment in the source pointed out by hpaulj seems to indicate that this is indeed the case. The array inside the list causes the list to be treated as a tuple, but the result is still advanced indexing due to the array. This particular special case does not seem to be documented.

Comment: _"it produces a copy instead of a view"_ - I wonder whether this could be considered a bug? It's normally desirable to produce a view wherever possible, right?

Comment: @Eric: I don't think so. The comment makes it clear that the list->tuple conversion was supposed to occur even in cases where the result would be advanced indexing instead of basic indexing; there's no interpretation where `a[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` could be basic indexing.

Comment: It's generally desirable to produce a view instead of a copy for operations that can do so consistently, but even though some advanced indexing operations could be implemented to return a view, they always make a copy for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 2):

With a dummy class I can determine how the interpreter translates `[...]` into calls to `__getitem__`.

```
In [1073]: class Foo():
      ...:     def __getitem__(idx):
      ...:         print(idx)
In [1080]: Foo()[1,2,slice(None)]
(1, 2, slice(None, None, None))
In [1081]: Foo()[(1,2,slice(None))]
(1, 2, slice(None, None, None))
In [1082]: Foo()[[1,2,slice(None)]]
[1, 2, slice(None, None, None)]
```

So wrapping multiple terms with () makes no difference - it gets a tuple in both cases.  And a list is passed as a list.

So the distinction between tuple and list (or not) must coded in `numpy` source code - which is compiled.  So I can't readily study it.

With a 1d array

indexing with a list produces the advanced indexing - picking specific values:

```
In [1085]: arr[[1,2,3]]
Out[1085]: array([ 0.73703368,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

but replacing one of those values with a tuple, or a slice:

```
In [1086]: arr[[1,2,(2,3)]]
IndexError: too many indices for array

In [1088]: arr[[1,2,slice(None)]] 
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

and the list is treated as a tuple - it tries matching values with dimensions.

So at a top level a list and tuple are treated the same - if the list can't interpreted as an advanced indexing list.

Notice also a difference which single item lists

```
In [1089]: arr[[1]]
Out[1089]: array([ 0.73703368])
In [1090]: arr[(1,)]
Out[1090]: 0.73703367969998546
In [1091]: arr[1]
Out[1091]: 0.73703367969998546
```

Some functions like `np.apply_along/over_axis` generate an index as list or array, and then apply it.  They work with a list or array because it is mutable.  Some then wrap it in `tuple` before use as index; others didn't bother.  That difference sort of bothered me, but these test case indicate that such a tuple wrapped often is optional.

```
In [1092]: idx=[1,2,slice(None)]
In [1093]: np.ones((2,3,4))[idx]
Out[1093]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
In [1094]: np.ones((2,3,4))[tuple(idx)]
Out[1094]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Looks like the tuple wrapper is still needed if I build the index as an object array:

```
In [1096]: np.ones((2,3,4))[np.array(idx)]
...
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
In [1097]: np.ones((2,3,4))[tuple(np.array(idx))]
Out[1097]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

===================

Comment from the function `@Eric` linked

```
    /*
     * Sequences < NPY_MAXDIMS with any slice objects
     * or newaxis, Ellipsis or other arrays or sequences
     * embedded, are considered equivalent to an indexing
     * tuple. (`a[[[1,2], [3,4]]] == a[[1,2], [3,4]]`)
     */
```

===================

This function wraps object arrays and lists in tuple for indexing:

```
def apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs):
     ....
     ind = [0]*(nd-1)
     i = zeros(nd, 'O')
     ....
     res = func1d(arr[tuple(i.tolist())], *args, **kwargs)
     outarr[tuple(ind)] = res
```

## update

Now this list indexing produces a `FutureWarning`:

```
In [113]: arr.shape
Out[113]: (2, 3, 4)
In [114]: arr[[1, 2, slice(None)]]
<ipython-input-114-f30c20184e42>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  arr[[1, 2, slice(None)]]
Out[114]: array([20, 21, 22, 23])
```

The changing the list to a tuple produces the same thing, without the warning:

```
In [115]: arr[(1, 2, slice(None))]
Out[115]: array([20, 21, 22, 23])
```

this is same thing as:

```
In [116]: arr[1, 2, :]
Out[116]: array([20, 21, 22, 23])
```

Indexing with commas creates a tuple which is passed to the `__setitem__` method.

The Warning says that in the future it will try to turn the list into an array instead of a tuple:

```
In [117]: arr[np.array([1, 2, slice(None)])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [117] in <module>
    arr[np.array([1, 2, slice(None)])]
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

But with the `slice` object this raises an error.  In that sense the `arr[tuple([....])]` interpretation is the only thing that makes sense.  But it's a legacy case, left over from an earlier `numeric` package.

Fortunately it's unlikely that a novice programmer will try this.  They may try `arr[[1,2,:]]`, but that will give a syntax error.  `:` is only allowed in indexing brackets, not in list brackets (or tuple () either).

This current round of comments was triggered by a differ case that produce the FutureWarning:

```
In [123]: arr[[[0, 1], [1, 0]]]
<ipython-input-123-4fa43c8569dd>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  arr[[[0, 1], [1, 0]]]
Out[123]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Here the nested list interpreted as a tuple with lists, or even:

```
In [124]: arr[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
Out[124]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [126]: arr[np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])].shape
Out[126]: (2, 2, 3, 4)
```

Same warning, but it isn't quite as obvious why the legacy code chose to take the tuple interpretation.  I don't see it  documented.

Comment: _"must coded in numpy source code - which is compiled. So I can't readily study it."_ - sure you can - I linked to the relevant function in a comment under my question ;)

Comment: I did qualify it with `readily`.  This function isn't as hard to decipher as some of the numpy C, but still not as testable as a Python function.

Comment: Fair. I'm trying to expose this in a python function in [numpy/numpy#8276](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8276), since parsing these weird corner cases is vital for any kind of `__getitem__` forwarding

Comment: Please correct me if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71500679/5290519) on this same page is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my conclusion:

1. The `[1,2]` apparently is a **1d-list**. And in this case, the **advanced indexing** is triggered. So `a[[1,2]]` has the same result as `a[[1,2],]`.
2. The `[1, np.array(2)]` is (treated as) a **2d-list**, even though `np.array(2)` is zero dimension. So `a[[1, np.array(2)]]` has the same result as `a[tuple([1, np.array(2)])]` and thus `a[1, 2]`, which gives the result `0.0`.

Comment: I don't think we need to  explain why `x[[1,2,slice(None)]]` is/was treated as `x[tuple([1,2,slice(None)])]`.  We just need to be aware of the issue, and avoid it where possible.