# Numpy array indexing behavior

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I was playing with numpy array indexing and find this odd behavior. When I index with `np.array` or `list` it works as expected:

```
 In[1]: arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
        arr[ [1, 1] ]
Out[1]: array([[2, 3],
               [2, 3]])
```

But when I put `tuple`, it gives me a single element:

```
 In[1]: arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
        arr[ (1, 1) ]
Out[1]: 3
```

Also some kind of this strange `tuple` vs `list` behavior occurs with `arr.flat`:

```
 In[1]: arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)

 In[2]: arr.flat[ [3, 4] ]
Out[2]: array([3, 4])

 In[3]: arr.flat[ (3, 4) ]
Out[3]: IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

I can't understand what is going on under the hood? What difference between `tuple` and `list` in this case?

Python 3.5.2
NumPy 1.11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is called fancy indexing, or [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). There's a difference between indexing with slices, or with a list/array. The trick is that multidimensional indexing actually works with tuples due to the implicit tuple syntax:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
arr[2,1] == arr[(2,1)] # exact same thing: 2,1 matrix element
```

However, using a *list* (or array) inside an index expression will behave differently:

```
arr[[2,1]]
```

will index into `arr` with 1, then with 2, so first it fetches `arr[2]==arr[2,:]`, then `arr[1]==arr[1,:]`, and returns these two rows (row 2 and row 1) as the result.

It gets funkier:

```
print(arr[1:3,0:2])
print(arr[[1,2],[0,1]])
```

The first one is regular indexing, and it slices rows 1 to 2 and columns 0 to 1 inclusive; giving you a 2x2 subarray. The second one is fancy indexing, it gives you `arr[1,0],arr[2,1]` in an array, i.e. it indexes selectively into your array using, essentially, the `zip()` of the index lists.

Now here's why `flat` works like that: it returns a `flatiter` of your array. From `help(arr.flat)`:

```
class flatiter(builtins.object)
 |  Flat iterator object to iterate over arrays.
 |  
 |  A `flatiter` iterator is returned by ``x.flat`` for any array `x`.
 |  It allows iterating over the array as if it were a 1-D array,
 |  either in a for-loop or by calling its `next` method.
```

So the resulting iterator from `arr.flat` behaves as a 1d array. When you do

```
arr.flat[ [3, 4] ]
```

you're accessing two elements of that virtual 1d array using fancy indexing; it works. But when you're trying to do

```
arr.flat[ (3,4) ]
```

you're attempting to access the `(3,4)` element of a 1d (!) array, but this is erroneous. The reason that this doesn't throw an IndexError is probably only due to the fact that `arr.flat` itself handles this indexing case.

Comment: Thank you for `tuple` insight, I really never thought about `tuple`'s implicit nature. And in the case of `flat`, I think it will be better if it raised: `too many indexes` because it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [387]: arr=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
```

With this list, you are selecting 2 rows from `arr`

```
In [388]: arr[[1,1]]
Out[388]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

It's the same as if you explicitly marked the column slice (with : or ...)

```
In [389]: arr[[1,1],:]
Out[389]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

Using an array instead of a list works: `arr[np.array([1,1]),:]`.  (It also eliminates some ambiguities.)

With the `tuple`, the result is the same as if you wrote the indexing without the tuple wrapper.  So it selects an element with row index of 1, column index of 1.

```
In [390]: arr[(1,1)]
Out[390]: 3
In [391]: arr[1,1]
Out[391]: 3
```

The `arr[1,1]` is translated by the interpreter to `arr.__getitem__((1,1))`.  As is common in Python `1,1` is shorthand for `(1,1)`.

In the `arr.flat` cases you are indexing the array as if it were 1d.  `np.arange(10)[[2,3]]` selects 2 items, while `np.arange(10)[(2,3)]` is 2d indexing, hence the error.

A couple of recent questions touch on a messier corner case.  Sometimes the list is treated as a tuple. The discussion might be enlightening, but don't go there if it's confusing.

[Advanced slicing when passed list instead of tuple in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598824/advanced-slicing-when-passed-list-instead-of-tuple-in-numpy)

[numpy indexing: shouldn't trailing Ellipsis be redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233678/numpy-indexing-shouldnt-trailing-ellipsis-be-redundant)