# Is there a canonical way of obtaining a 0D numpy subarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-indexing

Given a numpy `ndarray` and an index:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,4,(2,3,4))
idx = (1,1,1)
```

is there a clean way of retrieving the 0D subarray of `a` at `idx`?

Something equivalent to

```
a[idx + (None,)].squeeze()
```

but less hackish?

Note that @filippo's clever

```
a[idx][...]
```

is *not* equivalent. First, it doesn't work for object arrays. But more seriously it does not return a subarray but a new array:

```
b = a[idx][...]
b[()] = 7
a[idx] == 7
# False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = a[idx+(Ellipsis,)]
```

I'm testing on one machine and writing this a tablet, so can't give my usual verification code.

Perhaps the best documentation explanation (or statement of fact) is:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#detailed-notes

> When an ellipsis (...) is present but has no size (i.e. replaces zero :) the result will still always be an array. A view if no advanced index is present, otherwise a copy.

Comment: Funny, that's actually another counter example to my [very first post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41233678/7207392) on SO and guess who answered that one ...

Comment: Ok, let me challenge you to explain _why_ this actually works!

Comment: In `a[1,1,1,...]`, the `Ellipsis` means fill in the remaining dimensions, like a `[:]*`.  That can be 2, 1 or in this case 0.  I found a documentation note that states what happens even if it doesn't exactly explain the action.

Comment: Thanks! That's a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood properly what you want, does this look clean enough?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(2,3,4))
   ...: idx = (1,1,1)
   ...: 

In [3]: a[idx]
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: a[idx][...]
Out[4]: array(2)
```

EDIT: note that this returns a copy, not a 0D view of the same array

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! Thanks! But, alas, it doesn't work with object arrays. I've upated the question.

Comment: `a[idx+(Ellipsis,)]` seems to work.  It blends both ideas.  `a[idx]` for object array returns a `int`.  For `int` array it returns `np.int32`.  That is already a close cousin to a 0d array.  Look at its methods and attributes.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes! That's it. I think that's worth an answer. - Close cousin, yes, but it's mutability and sharing its data with the original array I'm after.

Comment: Uh, you're right, advanced indexing always copies if I recall correctly. Can't come up with anything better than @hpaulj though, please add an answer!