# get confused with numpy operation a[:] and a[...]

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, there exists some slicing operation like a[1:3,3:5], however I am confused with the operation a[:] and a[...],I am a novice at python, can anyone explain what's the difference between these?

Comment: `In python, there exists some slicing operation like a[1:3,3:5]` ... not in python.

Comment: Does python support `a[...]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think this was marked as duplicate to a wrong question as I guess OP is asking slice about `numpy`.

Comment: @Sraw No, python lists to not support indexing the the ellipsis operator (numpy arrays do). Also, the question is not tagged numpy, and I'm disinclined to reopen this...

Comment: There is something called [ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) but the documentation apparently doesn't bother to say what it means.

Comment: @ChrisMartin The docs are pretty clear. It is used for slicing in user-defined data types (such as numpy arrays. Try `arr[...]`). I don't think op refers to _that_ ellipsis in this question (the lack of clarity is another reason I'm not willing to reopen this).

Comment: @COLDSPEED sorry，I should modify my question. I just read some else's code using a[...] notation, the a is a numpy's ndarray.

Comment: A recent non trivial use of `Ellipsis` https://stackoverflow.com/q/47919869.  In indexing it means `0 or more :`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` is the Ellipsis, in pure Python it's basically a none-operator. It serves as a placeholder for code such as in this case:

```
while True:
    ...
```

Within numpy it serves a similar purpose, it's the do-not-slice operator. Since numpy supports multiple slices at the same time this can be useful. For example, to get the different edges of a cube:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: cube = numpy.arange(3**3).reshape(3, 3, 3)

In [3]: cube
Out[3]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

In [4]: cube[0, ..., 0]
Out[4]: array([0, 3, 6])

In [5]: cube[..., 0, 0]
Out[5]: array([ 0,  9, 18])

In [6]: cube[0, 0, ...]
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

It should be noted that `...` is functionally identical to `:` in the cases above, but it can be different for multi-dimensional objects:

```
In [7]: cube[..., 0]
Out[7]:
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
       [ 9, 12, 15],
       [18, 21, 24]])

In [8]: cube[:, 0]
Out[8]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [18, 19, 20]])
```

In multi-dimensional objects the `...` inserts the `:` as many times as needed to reach a full dimension

Answer (score 1):

`...` means 0 or more `:`.  By themselves they are most useful on the LHS (but see [Is there a canonical way of obtaining a 0D numpy subarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47919869) for a RHS use)

```
   arr[...] =1
```

assigns 1 to all elements of `arr`.  It works for all dimensions including a 0d array.

```
arr[:] =1
```

Works for a 1d array, and because trailing ':' are added automatically, higher dimensional arrays as well.  It does  not work on 0d arrays.

The Python object `Ellipsis` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis

is used by the interpreter when generating an indexing operation

```
a[...]   # implemented as
a.__getitem__((Ellipsis,))
```

Similarly a ':' is converted to a `slice(None)` object.

The usual Python objects like lists don't do anything with `Ellipsis`, but `numpy` arrays do use it.