# What is W[...,c] doing?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

What is this selection using "..." doing in this context?

`Z[i, h, w, c] = conv_single_step(a_slice_prev, W[...,c], b[...,c])`

Is it a similar operation to X[:,:] but with some other context that I am unable to find?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/773472/6689249)

Comment: And a more recent SO question on ':' v '...' (ellipsis), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975339/get-confused-with-numpy-operation-a-and-a