# Why does NumPy advanced indexing yield different results for list of lists and numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question about NumPy's advanced indexing.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598824/advanced-slicing-when-passed-list-instead-of-tuple-in-numpy) question, but I guess my question is slightly different.

In the example below `x_array` is the expected result. But when I tried the same with a list the result is different.

> From the numpy doc:
>
> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a
>   non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool),
>   or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type
>   integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer
>   and Boolean.

```
import numpy as np

vertices = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

idx_list = [[0, 1, 2],
            [0, 2, 1]]

x_list = vertices[idx_list]

print('list')

print(x_list)

#this works as expected
idx_array = np.array(idx_list)
x_array = vertices[idx_array]

print('array')
print(x_array)
```

`idx_list` should trigger advanced indexing as it is a "non-tuple sequence object?" Or is a list and a tuple the same here and it is "a tuple with at least one sequence object"

Using the list yields the same as when passing the two list entries separated by a comma within the square brackets (one for each dimension).

```
x_list_2 = vertices[idx_list[0], idx_list[1]]
```

This is also the behaviour I expect.

Comment: This is an inconsistency  that hasn't been cleaned up for historical reasons; there may be old code that expects this behavior.

Comment: So it is the same issue than in the link mentioned above?

Comment: Some ways down my answer in the link is a quote from the code (via `@Eric`) about a `sequence with ... sequences embedded`.  The example is like yours.  `vertices[idx_list], :]` tells it, explicitly, to apply `idx_list` to the 1st dimension, otherwise it is treating it as an `indexing tuple`.

Comment: So does the `Sequences` in `Sequences < NPY_MAXDIMS` refer to `len(idx_list)` or to the number of arguments within the square brackets like `x[arg1, arg2]` ?

Comment: It's always OK to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it comes down to what is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40599589/7919597

From numpy's indexing documentation:

> In order to remain backward compatible with a common usage in Numeric,
>   basic slicing is also initiated if the selection object is any
>   non-ndarray sequence (such as a list) containing slice objects, the
>   Ellipsis object, or the newaxis object, but not for integer arrays or
>   other embedded sequences.

The example with the list triggers an undocumented part of the backward compatibility logic, as described in a comment in the source code:

```
/*
 * Sequences < NPY_MAXDIMS with any slice objects
 * or newaxis, Ellipsis or other arrays or sequences
 * embedded, are considered equivalent to an indexing
 * tuple. (`a[[[1,2], [3,4]]] == a[[1,2], [3,4]]`)
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer doesn't explain anything. Here are the ideas:

First, since your `idx_list` is of dimension `2`, something is done in the background:

```py
idx_list = [[0, 1, 2],
            [0, 2, 1]]

x_list = vertices[tuple(idx_list)]  # wrapping with a `tuple()`
```

If you do this explicitly, you can get rid of the (annoying) *FutureWarning*:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

(this answers your OP) Second, your expected behaviour(`x_array`, `shape(2,3,3)`):

```
[[[0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]
  [6 7 8]]

 [[0 1 2]
  [6 7 8]
  [3 4 5]]]
```

can be done in either (as your OP):

```
vertices[np.array(idx_list)]
```

**or** by list, too:

```
vertices[tuple([list])]
# or this shorthand with warning
# vertices[[list]]
```

Notice that I've wrapped one additional bracket(`[list]`) to make sure that the first component of the resulting tuple is of dimension `2`, which results in the same meaning as `np.array(idx_list)`