# Whats the difference between `arr[tuple(seq)]` and `arr[seq]`? Relating to Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using an ndarray to slice another ndarray.
Normally I use `arr[ind_arr]`. `numpy` seems to not like this and raises a `FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use arr[tuple(seq)] instead of arr[seq]`.

What's the difference between `arr[tuple(seq)]` and `arr[seq]`?

Other questions on StackOverflow seem to be running into this error in `scipy` and `pandas` and most people suggest the error to be in the particular version of these packages. I am running into the warning running purely in `numpy`.

Example posts:

[FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52110869/7530580)

[FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52594235/7530580)

[FutureWarning with distplot in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53334421/7530580)

MWE reproducing warning:

```
import numpy as np

# generate a random 2d array
A = np.random.randint(20, size=(7,7))
print(A, '\n')

# define indices
ind_i = np.array([1, 2, 3])  # along i
ind_j = np.array([5, 6])  # along j

# generate index array using meshgrid
ind_ij = np.meshgrid(ind_i, ind_j, indexing='ij')

B = A[ind_ij]
print(B, '\n')

C = A[tuple(ind_ij)]
print(C, '\n')

# note: both produce the same result
```

Answer (score 3):

`meshgrid` returns a list of arrays:

```
In [50]: np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5],indexing='ij')                                                      
Out[50]: 
[array([[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]]), array([[4, 5],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 5]])]
In [51]: np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5],indexing='ij',sparse=True)                                          
Out[51]: 
[array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[4, 5]])]
```

`ix_` does the same thing, but returns a tuple:

```
In [52]: np.ix_([1,2,3],[4,5])                                                                         
Out[52]: 
(array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[4, 5]]))
```

`np.ogrid` also produces the list.

```
In [55]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
```

indexing with the `ix` tuple:

```
In [56]: arr[_52]                                                                                      
Out[56]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [16, 17],
       [22, 23]])
```

indexing with the `meshgrid` list:

```
In [57]: arr[_51]                                                                                      
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[57]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [16, 17],
       [22, 23]])
```

Often the `meshgrid` result is used with unpacking:

```
In [62]: I,J = np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5],indexing='ij',sparse=True)                                    
In [63]: arr[I,J]                                                                                      
Out[63]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [16, 17],
       [22, 23]])
```

Here `[I,J]` is the same as `[(I,J)]`, making a tuple of the 2 subarrays.

Basically they are trying to remove a loophole that existed for historical reasons.  I don't know if they can change the handling of `meshgrid` results without causing further compatibility issues.

Comment: Its useful to know the alternatives, thanks.

So do we know how the results would be different (as indicated by the `FutureWarning ...which will result either in an error or a different result`)? And otherwise should I try to stick to tuples or unpacked indices as opposed to `arr[seq]`?

Comment: It may try `arr[np.array(idx),...]`, turning the meshgrid list into an array that indexes just the first dimension.

Comment: Did I missing something? `arr[_51]`, `arr[_52]` and `arr[I, J]` give identical results, so where is the difference?

Comment: @Jason, yes they produce the same thing (except for the warning).  That was my point.

Answer (score 0):

For Future *Readers* having this `FutureWarning: ...` and want to correctly resolve them.

1. Read the answer of @hpaulj here. And notice **the point** is when he(she) said:

   > [...] returns **a list** of [...]
   >
   > [...] returns **a tuple** of [...]
2. If you don't know why 1. is the point please read the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71487259/5290519, which is also written by him(her). This answer provides:

   - **Why**, in the first place, the usage of **list** as index will cause a warning.

     > [4] is a problem because in the past, certain lists were interpreted as though they were tuples. This is a legacy case that developers are trying to cleanup, hence the FutureWarning.
   - A series of **concise** examples on the (correct) usage of `list`,`tuple`,`np.array` as array index.
3. If you still don't get the point, try my own answer after I figuring  all these complicated concepts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71493474/5290519